# Is there anyway we can get report of word track changes in table or text format?

Tags: excel, ms-word

If the word file is at common directory and many people have read write access to it.
Suppose multiple person did multiple changes including format changes, text and all other changes, then our report should have all this data.

Report should have 3 columns

1. Page no 2) Changed by 3) DateTime

Report can be in either word format or excel format.

Also, is there anyway to restrict someone from format changes only?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for programming questions on specific projects, not brain-storming or recommendations. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/133132-post2.html